# Manage SSH Users with MySQL backend

Tags: linux, ssh, ldap

is there a possibility to use a (mysql) Database to manage SSH login credentials instead of /etc/passwd ?

I know I could use ldap but I only want simple user management and ldap seems a little bit overpowered for this job.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Linux authentication is based around the pluggable authentication modules (PAM) which allows for easy switching from one authentication backend to another. Simply install and configure a PAM MySQL module, with a corresponding user database in MySQL.

Pre-compiled packages are available in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) archive for RHEL/CentOS as `pam_mysql` and a `pam-mysql` package should be available in  Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for. Sometimes its hard to google when you don't know the exact terms ;)

Answer (score 4):

While PAM-MySQL can manage login credentials, it is an incomplete solution, since it only handles the authentication portion.  It does not create a user account on the system.  For example:

- `ls -l` will not use PAM-MySQL to resolve UIDs to usernames.
- [The user's home directory is not stored in MySQL.](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/Documentation/FAQ.php?seemore=y#q3)

In other words, PAM-MySQL is a replacement for `/etc/shadow`, not for `/etc/passwd`.  You will need to either create both an `/etc/passwd` entry *and* a MySQL entry for each user, or supplement PAM-MySQL with [NSS MySQL](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/nss-mysql).

LDAP is indeed the better tool for the job, as you will be able to centralize the user account information in one place.  I don't believe it is overpowered.  Rather it's a kind of database that is specially designed to manage user accounts, so best practice would be to just use LDAP as a standard solution rather than hacking together a non-standard system with MySQL.  Either OpenLDAP or 389 Directory Server would be a more appropriate user database than MySQL.  (Both of them can be configured to use an SQL back-end, if you insist.)

Comment: Agreed. LDAP can even be used with a MySQL backend if needed.